# Left border for all rows

Tags: html, css

[image: Screenshot]

I can't make border-left all for all rows.
Is it possible without CSS?

style="border-left: 1px solid #000;">

This should be in all rows, but it's not. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<p style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000; color: -internal-quirk-inherit;">&nbsp;</p>
<table style="background-color: white; font-family: lato; text-align: left; color: #000000; font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; padding: 10px; height: 42px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="width: 100px; padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px; text-align: center; height: 42px;" rowspan="4">
        <p>
          <a href="www.jemiol.com"><img src="http://serwer1528495.home.pl/jemiol/SIGNATURE/JEMIOL.png" width="100px" /></a>
        </p>
        <p>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/LukaszJemiol"><img src="http://serwer1528495.home.pl/jemiol/SIGNATURE/FACEBOOK.png" width="25px" /></a>&nbsp;
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/lukaszjemiol/"><img src="http://serwer1528495.home.pl/jemiol/SIGNATURE/INSTAGRAM.png" width="25px" /></a>&nbsp;
          <a href="https://pl.linkedin.com/company/lukaszjemiol"><img src="http://serwer1528495.home.pl/jemiol/SIGNATURE/LINKEDIN.png" width="25px" /></a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 19px; height: 42px;" rowspan="4">
        <p style="border-left: 1px solid #000;">&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; font-weight: bold; width: 344px; height: 1px;" colspan="4">DAMIAN DĄBROWSKI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 1px;">
      <td style="padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; width: 344px; height: 10px;" colspan="4">ADMINISTRATOR STRONY INTERNETOWEJ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 1px;">
      <td style="padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; width: 344px; height: 21px;" colspan="4"><a style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;" href="-">-</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 1px;">
      <td style="padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; width: 344px; height: 10px;" colspan="4"><a style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;" href="-">-</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p style="border-top: 1px solid #000; color: -internal-quirk-inherit;">&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: How would it be possible without css? Old table attributes or something?

Comment: You only have border on the P, how would that give a border on the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you only have border on the P tag

You mean

```
 <td style="width: 19px; height: 42px; border-left: 1px solid #000;" rowspan="4">
```

```html
<p style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000; color: -internal-quirk-inherit;">&nbsp;</p>
<table style="background-color: white; font-family: lato; text-align: left; color: #000000; font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; padding: 10px; height: 42px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 21px; ">
      <td style="width: 100px; padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px; text-align: center; height: 42px;" rowspan="4">
        <p>
          <a href="www.jemiol.com"><img src="http://serwer1528495.home.pl/jemiol/SIGNATURE/JEMIOL.png" width="100px" /></a>
        </p>
        <p>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/LukaszJemiol"><img src="http://serwer1528495.home.pl/jemiol/SIGNATURE/FACEBOOK.png" width="25px" /></a>&nbsp;
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/lukaszjemiol/"><img src="http://serwer1528495.home.pl/jemiol/SIGNATURE/INSTAGRAM.png" width="25px" /></a>&nbsp;
          <a href="https://pl.linkedin.com/company/lukaszjemiol"><img src="http://serwer1528495.home.pl/jemiol/SIGNATURE/LINKEDIN.png" width="25px" /></a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 19px; height: 42px; border-left: 1px solid #000;" rowspan="4">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; font-weight: bold; width: 344px; height: 1px;" colspan="4">DAMIAN DĄBROWSKI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 1px;">
      <td style="padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; width: 344px; height: 10px;" colspan="4">ADMINISTRATOR STRONY INTERNETOWEJ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 1px;">
      <td style="padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; width: 344px; height: 21px;" colspan="4"><a style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;" href="-">-</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 1px;">
      <td style="padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; width: 344px; height: 10px;" colspan="4"><a style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;" href="-">-</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p style="border-top: 1px solid #000; color: -internal-quirk-inherit;">&nbsp;</p>
```